# Rails App crashes when deployed to Heroku, but logs claim everything is fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

OK, so I deploying a very basic app to Heroku. I've followed [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3) to the letter. Everything about this deployment was textbook, but when I open the site on Heroku, I get the frustratingly vague message "We're sorry, but something went wrong."

When I do "heroku ps" it says:

```
    Process  State       Command                               
    -------  ----------  ------------------------------------  
    web.1    up for 13m  bundle exec rails server thin -p $..
```

When I run "heroku logs" I get the usual deprecation messages and then the text below.  But I don't see any red flags in these logs that would cause the app to crash.  Am I missing something?

```
    2012-06-24T12:50:50+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
    2012-06-24T12:51:25+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by a@example.com      2012-06-24T12:51:25+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy ff89ee6 by a@example.com
    2012-06-24T12:51:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to bouncing
    2012-06-24T12:51:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from bouncing to created
    2012-06-24T12:51:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
    2012-06-24T12:51:25+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
    2012-06-24T12:51:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server thin -p 37816 -e production`
    2012-06-24T12:51:27+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2012-06-24T12:51:28+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2012-06-24T12:51:29+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
    2012-06-24T12:51:34+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Thin
    2012-06-24T12:51:34+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.2.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:37816
    2012-06-24T12:51:34+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    2012-06-24T12:51:34+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
    2012-06-24T12:51:34+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
    2012-06-24T12:51:34+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
    2012-06-24T12:51:34+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
    2012-06-24T12:51:34+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:37816, CTRL+C to stop
    2012-06-24T12:51:35+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I wasn't showing enough records.  Once I ran `heroku logs -n 2000` (or some other large number), it showed me the problem that was right at the start of things

Answer (score 1):

Did you migrate your database, if you have one? That's something that often catches me. :-)

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Yeah, I did.  That's part of why I'm confused.  I did all the usual stuff, but it still crashed.